# How to extract log details using grok expression

Tags: logstash-grok

Below is our log entry and we want extractct below highlighted values using 
Grok expression -http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/discover

> sys tmp usr var Purging cache - END (PID: 4477, QN: **51**/**51**, ET:
>   **0**) anaconda-post.log bin dev etc home lib lib64 lost+found media mnt opt

Required help to get above values ing Grok expression

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
QN: %{NUMBER:QN1}/%{NUMBER:QN2}, ET: %{NUMBER:ET}
```

Results in the following output:

```
{
  "QN1": [
    [
      "51"
    ]
  ],
  "BASE10NUM": [
    [
      "51",
      "51",
      "0"
    ]
  ],
  "QN2": [
    [
      "51"
    ]
  ],
  "ET": [
    [
      "0"
    ]
  ]
}
```